# How to parse an array of json object to typescript (object) after a get method

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am a beginner in angular and start to build my first app.My goal is to build a generic service that will be inherited from others service. I am following the structure of this link to my approach [Generic HTTP Service](https://medium.com/@krishna.acondy/a-generic-http-service-approach-for-angular-applications-a7bd8ff6a068) .In read method i`m using Serializer class to convert the response json object to my typescript an it work. I got a map error. How can I solve it?

Service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Resource } from '../models/resource.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Serializer } from '../serializer/serializer';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService<T extends Resource> {

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private url: string,
    private endpoint: string,
    private authentication: AuthenticationService,
    private serializer: Serializer
  ) { }


  create(resource: T) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.url}/${this.endpoint}`, JSON.stringify(resource), { headers: headers });
  }



  //PUT
  update(item: T): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpClient.put<T>(`${this.url}/${this.endpoint}`, JSON.stringify(item), { headers: this.addHeaders() })
      .map(data => this.serializer.fromJson(data) as T);
  }



  //GET
  read(id: number): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.url}/${this.endpoint}/${id}`, { headers: this.addHeaders() })
      .map((data: any) => this.serializer.fromJson(data) as T);
  }

  //GET ALL
  list(): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<T>(`${this.url}/${this.endpoint}` , {headers : this.addHeaders()})
      .map((data: any) =>
        this.convertData(data.items));
  }

  protected convertData(data: any): T[] {

    return data.map(item => {this.serializer.fromJson(item)});
  }

  protected addHeaders() {
    let token = ('Bearer ' + this.authentication.getToken()).valueOf();
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8').set('Authorization', token);
    return headers;
  }

}
```

UserService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from './shared.service';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { User } from '../models/user/user.model';
import { AuthenticationService } from 'app/service/authentication.service';
import { UserSerializer } from '../serializer/user-serializer';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Injectable()
export class UserService extends SharedService<User>{

  constructor(httpClient: HttpClient, authenticate: AuthenticationService) {
    super(httpClient,
      'http://localhost:8084/SuperCloud/webresources',
      'user',
      authenticate,
      new UserSerializer()
    );
  }
```

UserSerializer:

```
import { User } from "../models/user/user.model";
import { Serializer } from "./serializer";
import { Resource } from "../models/resource.model";

export class UserSerializer extends Serializer {
    fromJson(json: any): Resource {
        const user = new User();
        user.id = json.id;
        user.name = json.name;
        user.surname = json.surname;
        user.email = json.email;
        user.phoneNumber = json.phoneNumber;
        user.password = json.password;
        user.username = json.username;
        user.active = json.active;
        console.log('serializer');
        console.log(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

User model:

```
import { Resource } from "../resource.model";

export class User extends Resource{
    username: string;
    email: string;
    name: string;
    surname: string;
    phoneNumber: string;
    password?: string;
    active : boolean;
}
```

UserService inherited inherited:

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.userService.list().subscribe(
            (data) => console.log(data)
       );
 
    }
```

Error:

> core.es5.js:1020 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of
> undefined
>
> at UserService.SharedService.convertData (shared.service.ts:53)
> at MapSubscriber.eval [as project] (shared.service.ts:48)
> at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:79)
> at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
> at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)
> at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
> at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:90)
> at FilterSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
> at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:151)
> at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:25)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I assume the data that you passed into `convertData` function is not an array.
Only `Array` or `Observable` have `map` function in this case.
Also, chained function has been changed into `pipeable operators` in RxJS 6 
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Secondly, looking at the error message - I don't think the data value returned from the endpoint has value.

Third, `data.map(item => {this.serializer.fromJson(item)});` - if the arrow function inside the map function is wrapped in curly bracket, you need to have `return` keyword.
in other word, `data.map(item => {this.serializer.fromJson(item)});` should be `data.map(item => this.serializer.fromJson(item));` or `data.map(item => {return this.serializer.fromJson(item)});`

Comment: Only the second it wasn't a problem.i change my code after your suggestions.   list() : Observable<T[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.url}/${this.endpoint}`, { headers: this.addHeaders() }).pipe(
      map((data : T[]) => (this.convertData(data))) 
    )
  }

  protected convertData(data: any): T[] {
    return data.map(item => { return this.serializer.fromJson(item) });
  }

Comment: The function is working!!Can i have a link really for beginners with pipe and chain examples

Comment: RxJS recently moved their documentation website to https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com it's a good place to begin.

Answer (score 0):

Use subscribe instead of map to return the response.

```
 return this.httpClient
  .put<T>(`${this.url}/${this.endpoint}`, JSON.stringify(item), {
    headers: this.addHeaders()
  })
  .subscribe(data => this.serializer.fromJson(data) as T);
```

BTW RXJs6 has changed the [implementation of using observable map function](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#howto-convert-to-pipe-syntax)

Comment: I have subscribe in my componet my problem is in list() function.

Comment: You can still subscribe in service class.  `list(): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<T>(`${this.url}/${this.endpoint}`, { headers: this.addHeaders() }).subscribe((data: any) => this.convertData(data.items));
  }`